# How to Iterate through List of Object arrays

Tags: java, hibernate

So right now I have a program containing a piece of code that looks like this...

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.max("price"));
projList.add(Projections.min("price"));
projList.add(Projections.countDistinct("description"));
crit.setProjection(projList);
List results = crit.list();
```

I want to iterate results.So thank you in advance for any help/advice that is offered.

Comment: If this is schoolwork tag it as such. Otherwise, List<Product> results = crit.list(); and then for (Product p: results) {}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case you will have a list whose elements is an array of the following:
[maxPrice,minPrice,count].

```
....
List<Object[]> results = crit.list();

for (Object[] result : results) {
    Integer maxPrice = (Integer)result[0];
    Integer minPrice = (Integer)result[1];
    Long count = (Long)result[2];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use Generic in List and for each but for current code you could do following to iterate

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < results.size() ; i++){
 Foo foo = (Foo) results.get(i);

}
```

Or better to go for readable for-each loop

```
for(Foo foo: listOfFoos){
  // access foo here
}
```

Comment: Or maybe use an iterator if you want to be slightly more modern? like for (Iterator<Product> pi = results.iterator(); pi.hasNext();) { Product p = pi.next();}

Comment: Yeah, but this solution is old school and low-tech!  Who couldn't possibly like it?

Comment: It is not possible to cast  (object[]) object array to a object like Foo

Answer (score 5):

You can probably do something like this:

```
for (Object result : results) {
    // process each result
}
```