# Object List of Array mapping to List of Pojo

Tags: java, spring-boot, dozer

I have a JDBC Result set as `List<Object[]>` & need to convert it to `List<ObjectType>` in Spring boot.

```
// Input Object Array returned by below code
List<Object[]> resultObj = query.getResultList();
// Ex
resultObj[0][0] = new Integer(10);
resultObj[0][1] = "Test";
resultObj[0][2] = "Hello";

// Need map resultObj to List<ObjectType> below type

class ObjectType {
    //maps to Object[0]
    private Integer x;
    //maps to Object[1]
    private String y;
    //maps to Object[2]
    private String z;
}
```

Since object[] has over 18 elements, instead of mapping manually each index to field of POJO, i tried using Dozer.

```
<mapping>
        <class-a>java.lang.Object[]</class-a>
        <class-b>com.ObjectType</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>this[0]</a>
            <b>x</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>this[1]</a>
            <b>y</b>
        </field>
</mapping>
```

I tried following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26556413/350705, but output mapped object has below value - same value for all fields & address space as value

```
"x": "[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d716a1c",
"y": "[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d716a1c",
"z": "[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d716a1c",
```

Please suggest if there is any other configurable approach for this.

Comment: can you provide the sample values of List<Object[]> and the expected output. see if this helps you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600724/how-to-iterate-through-list-of-object-arrays

Comment: @NKR: I have updated sample input & input type to question.

Comment: @NKR: I am trying  to avoid that manual mapping suggested in that question's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601960/350705.

Answer (score 0):

Try something below that might help. For explanation please refer this link https://sourceforge.net/p/dozer/discussion/452530/thread/012023da/

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.lang.Object[]</class-a>
    <class-b>com.ObjectType</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>this</a>
        <b set-method="add(java.lang.Object)" type="iterate">anything</b>
        <b-hint>your destination object type</b-hint>
    </field>
```

Comment: The Dozer content on SourceForge is outdated.  Dozer has moved to GitHub https://dozermapper.github.io/